# Проблема с Box2D...

Tags: box2d, c++

Здравствуйте, подключаю Box2D и некую библиотеку - вылетает куча ошибок.

C чем это связно? По отдельности библиотеки работают нормально. Спасибо.

> `error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall b2World::~b2World(void)" (??1b2World@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl AppMain(void)" (?AppMain@@YAXXZ)
> 1>App.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall b2World::Step(float,int,int)" (?Step@b2World@@QAEXMHH@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl AppMain(void)" (?AppMain@@YAXXZ)
> 1>App.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: class b2Fixture * __thiscall b2Body::CreateFixture(struct b2FixtureDef const *)" (?CreateFixture@b2Body@@QAEPAVb2Fixture@@PBUb2FixtureDef@@@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl AppMain(void)" (?AppMain@@YAXXZ)
> 1>App.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: class b2Fixture * __thiscall b2Body::CreateFixture(class b2Shape const *,float)" (?CreateFixture@b2Body@@QAEPAVb2Fixture@@PBVb2Shape@@M@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl AppMain(void)" (?AppMain@@YAXXZ)
> 1>App.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall b2PolygonShape::SetAsBox(float,float)" (?SetAsBox@b2PolygonShape@@QAEXMM@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl AppMain(void)" (?AppMain@@YAXXZ)
> 1>App.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: class b2Body * __thiscall b2World::CreateBody(struct b2BodyDef const *)" (?CreateBody@b2World@@QAEPAVb2Body@@PBUb2BodyDef@@@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl AppMain(void)" (?AppMain@@YAXXZ)
> 1>App.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall b2World::b2World(struct b2Vec2 const &)" (??0b2World@@QAE@ABUb2Vec2@@@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl AppMain(void)" (?AppMain@@YAXXZ)
> 1>App.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual class b2Shape * __thiscall b2PolygonShape::Clone(class b2BlockAllocator *)const " (?Clone@b2PolygonShape@@UBEPAVb2Shape@@PAVb2BlockAllocator@@@Z)
> 1>App.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual int __thiscall b2PolygonShape::GetChildCount(void)const " (?GetChildCount@b2PolygonShape@@UBEHXZ)`

Answer (score 1):

Подобного рода ошибки могут возникать, если линкуемые библиотеки скомпилированы с разными версиями библиотек времени исполнения (C Runtime).

Comment: А как избавиться от такой ошибки?